# UICollectionView cell with constant heigh and dynamic width depending on UIImageView width

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

How can I set the collection view cell width depending on image view. I have tried with the give code below but the width is same for all cell. I have set the height constraint of image view as 100 and width constrain >= 50 and content mode as aspect fit.
`if let flowLayout = itemOfferCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout { flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize }`

Answer (score 0):

I have housed this settings for layout in order to make it selfSizing

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

You also have to set constraints of your contentView and imageView in cell like this

```
contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true

imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```